# Will it be successfully published by google play console if having security issue?

Tags: android, google-play-console

I uploaded my app to google play console. After one day , it showed the security issue. If I neglect this will it be a concern about publish status(published, rejected, suspended)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is there is a key which probably hard-coded. It's not advisable to use it as plain text hard-coded in Java code.

Although you should store it in your `string.xml` in that way:

```
<string name="KEY">Your_key</string>
```

so, your app might be rejected.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use the cpp which returns your key which should be secure 
 using native NDK. [CLick here](https://www.codementor.io/blog/kotlin-apikeys-7o0g54qk5b) this link which helps you out for implementation